# URL to add calendar event to iCloud

Tags: google-calendar, apple-ical, icloud

Is there a URL that will let me offer an <kbd>Add to iCloud Calendar</kbd> button to my site?

I'm not an iCloud user, but I expect it's possible to use iCloud just via the web, without using the native iCal app.

Comment: Some reference stuff:    **Google calendar** offers [a special URL](http://www.google.com/googlecalendar/event_publisher_guide.html#toc-individual) that let's people add an event to their Google Calendar.     **For Outlook and iCal**, you can generate and post a [.ics file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) for people to download.  _(PS - Sorry if this belongs on the 'Web Applications' exchange site, it wasn't clear to me where it fit better!)_